# Glassfish doesn't want to run any project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm Runing Netbeans 7.1.2 with Glassfish Server 3.1.2, the problem when I click Run>ProjectTest, shows me those messages in the output, and Still long time and doesn't show anything.

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.2
```

in other tab,shows this message.

```
 Thu Aug 30 18:46:22 WEST 2012 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
 Thu Aug 30 18:46:23 WEST 2012 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.1.2 - (1095077) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netbeans, click on your Services tab, expand the Servers node, and find your GlassFish server and expand its node. There will be an applications folder with your project inside of it. If the project is deployed, you can right click on your project and select the Open in Browser option if the IDE didn't launch it for you.

You can also click on the GlashFish Server tab in out the Netbeans Output tab to check the output for exceptions, errors, etc...

Comment: ok, I had other version of glassfish 3+ I changed I changed 3.1.2 to glassfish 3+, it works fine. thank you.